# доступ к стороннему USB устройству с проприетарным драйвером

Tags: usb, доступ, драйвер, принтер

Есть принтер, подключаемый обычным usb кабелем в обычный компьютер с операционной системой windows 10, этот принтер поддерживает PJL

У этого принтера есть собственный драйвер, при наличии которого можно распечатывать страницы.

*Вопрос заключается в следующем:*
Как обратиться к принтеру через usb интерфейс?

*Что известно на данный момент*:
Если использовать libusb, то требуется установка драйвера, например через zadig, и проблема с доступом к принтеру решается, но он перестаёт печатать до удаления драйвера winusb и установки родного драйвера принтера.

Если пробовать общаться с принтером без установки драйвера вроде WinUsb, то можно прочитать список интерфейсов, но нельзя в них отправлять данные(ошибка доступа).

Существует ли способ указать, что моя программа работает с принтером через мой драйвер, а остальные через стандартный?

В какую сторону копать?